# Temporarily unpack dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, unpack

Say, I have a dic like this

```
my_dictionary = {'a':1,'c':5,'b':20,'d':7}
```

Now, I want to do this with my dic:

```
if my_dictionary['a'] == 1 and my_dictionary['d'] == 7:
    print my_dictionary['c']
```

This looks ridiculous because I am typing my_dictionary 3 times!

**So is there any syntax which would allow me to do something like this:**

```
within my_dictionary:
    if a == 1 and d == 7:
        print c
```

---

This would actually work if I didn't have anything more (in this case b) in my dic:

```
def f(a,d,c):
    if a == 1 and d == 7:
        print c 

f(**my_dictionary)
```

Comment: My understanding is that dictionaries are generally for "unrelated items." But in your case c is related to a and d. Does it need to be a dictionary? Will you always lookup 2 values and return a third or will you lookup n values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your function to

```
def f(a,d,c,**args):
    if a == 1 and d == 7:
        print c
```

then it will work even if you have other items in the dict.

Comment: Cool! I was almost there :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to minimize multiple indexing :

```
>>> if operator.itemgetter('a','d')(my_dictionary)==(1,7):
...      print operator.itemgetter('c')(my_dictionary)
```

And you can use it in a function :

```
>>> def get_item(*args):
...   return operator.itemgetter(*args)(my_dictionary)
... 
>>> 
>>> if get_item('a','d')==(1,7):
...      print get_item('c')
... 
5
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer

> So is there any syntax which would allow me to do something like this:
>
> ```
> within my_dictionary:
> if a == 1 and d == 7:
>     print c
> ```

You can subclass dict so that it has `with` magic methods. To do this, the class must have `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. You could then export the keys to the local scope of the with statement and clean them up with the exit method.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8178726/3398583) I was able to create a subclass that did so:

```
import inspect
import ctypes

locals_to_fast = ctypes.pythonapi.PyFrame_LocalsToFast
locals_to_fast.restype = None
locals_to_fast.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object, ctypes.c_int]

class WithDict(dict):
    def __enter__(self):
        frame = self.get_frame()
        for k,v in self.iteritems():
            frame.f_locals[str(k)] = v
            locals_to_fast(frame, 1)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        frame = self.get_frame()
        for k in self.keys():
            del frame.f_locals[str(k)]

    def get_frame(self):
        return inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[2][0]
```

A test case using your original example

```
my_dictionary = WithDict({'a':1,'c':5,'b':20,'d':7})
with my_dictionary:
    if a == 1 and d == 7:
        print c
```

prints `5`

The variables get deleted when the `with` statement completes

Comment: Thanks! This seems very useful info. I am not familiar with `with` , `__exit__`  and `__enter__` and for my particular problem this is probably too much like killing bees with nuclear missiles. Nevertheless seems to be something I need to take a look at.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that as I was writing it, it was a nice excersise anyway. You could make it (even more?) nasty by monkey patching `dict` and using bytecode manipulation so you could literally use the {} syntax but that would really be like using nukes!