# Changing existing list using matplotlib event in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, global-variables

I am working on an program to identify significant frequencies in a power density spectrum. I have found a list of significant peaks in a automated way. But now I want to look at them visually and add / delete peaks from a plot using **fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', ontype)** (http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html)

As I want to add multiple peaks I want to update the used list. Though I get a *UnboundLocalError: local variable 'frequencyLIST' referenced before assignment* error.

```
def interactiveMethod(frequency,PDS, frequencyLIST,figureName):
#frequency and PDS is the input list of data, frequencyLIST is my found list of
#frequencies and figureName is the figure I previously made which I want to use the
#event on.

 def ontype(event):
  if event.key == 'a':
   #Getting the event xdata
   x = event.xdata      
   frequencyCut = frequency[np.where((frequency > x - 2) & (frequency < x + 2))]
   PDSCut = PDS[np.where((frequency > x - 2) & (frequency < x + 2))]

   #Find the maximum PDS, as this corresponds to a peak
   PDSMax = np.max(PDSCut)
   frequencyMax = frequencyCut[np.where(PDSCut == PDSMax)][0]

   #Updating the new list using the found frequency
   frequencyLIST = np.append(frequencyLIST,frequencyMax)

 figureName.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event',ontype)
```

I have no idea where I should put this frequencyLIST so I can update it.

python version: 2.7.3 32bit

matplotlib version: 1.3.0

numpy version: 1.7.1

ubuntu 13.1

I also have enthough canopy (not sure which version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the `frequencyLIST` variable to the outermost method (`interactiveMethod`) but not to the inner method (`ontype`). A quick fix is to add the following line to the inner method:

```
def ontype(event):
    global frequencyLIST
    # ... following lines unaltered ...
```

You can read more on the way Python scopes variables, and a quirk similar to yours, in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218895/python-nested-functions-variable-scoping)

Comment: It doesn't seem fixed. It gives me the error message *NameError: global name 'frequencyLIST' is not defined*. I am running out of ideas. I will test if I can pass multiple arguments to the mpl_connect but I doubt it.

Comment: Apparently it is a problem with np.array or np.append. When I work with normal lists there is no problem.

Comment: Yes, the `np.append` does not change the list in-place. It returns a new list (array) with the new element at the end. Is working with normal lists enough for your solution?

Comment: Yes. Working with normal lists is no problem. It makes bookkeeping only a little bit less clear. As the frequencyLIST in my actual code is a 6 by N matrix. But is the way to go!