# Passing parameter to inner function

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I have a function with inner function. I wonder what is a proper way to pass variables to inner function. From what I can see tables are passed by default, although I am not sure whether this is a undocumented workaround or python design.

```
def function():
    def inner_function():
        if a[0] > b[0]:
            print("a[0] = {0}, b[0] = {1}".format(a[0], b[0]))
            tmp = c
            c = d
            d = tmp
        
    a = [4, 3]
    b = [2, 1]
    c = 1
    d = 2
    
    inner_function()
    
function()
```

python test.py output:

> $ python test.py a[0] = 4, b[0] = 2 Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "test.py", line 16, in
>
> function()
>
> ```
>    File "test.py", line 14, in function
> ```
>
> inner_function()
>
> ```
>    File "test.py", line 5, in inner_function
> ```
>
> tmp = c
>
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment

What is a proper way to pass variables from "function" to "inner_function"? Is there any other way than by parameter? Why there is an error on "c" variable reference and not on "a" table?

Comment: Why not just send the variables as arguments to the inner function and then return them back out?

Comment: Which python version are you using? This is important here, because python3 has a specific keyword for this occasion: https://www.smallsurething.com/a-quick-guide-to-nonlocal-in-python-3/

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK `c` is throwing an error because is assigned inside `inner_function` so it is a different variable than the `c` variable defined in `function`. Variables `a` and `b` work because they are only read at `inner_function` so they are not being redefined. Renaming `c` and `d` to `new_c` and `new_d` make it works.

https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/184e1778-adb7-4759-8951-da699751c31e/

More info about [Python nested functions variable scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218895/python-nested-functions-variable-scoping)

```
def function():
    def inner_function():
        if a[0] > b[0]:
            print("a[0] = {0}, b[0] = {1}".format(a[0], b[0]))
            tmp = c
            new_c = d
            new_d = tmp

    a = [4, 3]
    b = [2, 1]
    c = 1
    d = 2

    inner_function()

function()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to state c and d variables as global (by the way this is not a good idea )

```
def function():
global c,d
a = [4, 3]
b = [2, 1]
c = 1
d = 2
def inner_function():
    if a[0] > b[0]:
        global c,d
        print("a[0] = {0}, b[0] = {1}".format(a[0], b[0]))
        tmp = c
        c = d
        d = tmp
inner_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess a Pythonic way definitely refers to a duck and a rabbit, possibly even a knight. I'd also second @Metareven on passing them in as arguments as Python has a very succinct way of handling them. This way you do not need to worry about @global variables. And you have a good idea about what goes in and as suggested what comes out.

```
def function(duck):
    def inner_function(rabbit):
        if rabbit[0][0] > rabbit[1][0]:
            print("a[0] aka the first one behind the rabbit = {0}, \nb[0] aka the second one behind the rabbit = {1}".format(rabbit[0], rabbit[1]))
            tmp = rabbit[2]
            rabbit[2] = rabbit[3]
            rabbit[3] = tmp
    inner_function(duck)

#Let's sort out the arguments
a = [4, 3]
b = [2, 1]
c = 1
d = 2


function([a,b,c,d])
```

The function call returns the following:

```
python innner.py
a[0] aka the first one behind the rabbit = [4, 3], 
b[0] aka the second one behind the rabbit = [2, 1]
```

Has this answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

Although your question has been answered I am not sure it is clear why your code produce this error.

Anyway to make it clear the line that causes problem is `c = d` although your interpreter disagrees. 
Let me explain a bit. You are inside `inner_function()` and without these lines (`c = d` and `d = tmp`) you are referring to variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` assigned outside of `inner_function()`. So, implicitly you are referring to these variable (`a`, `b`, `c` and `d` that is) as `global`.
The moment you assign a value to a variable inside an inner function then the interpreter consider it to be local variable of this function. In this case `c` is considered local now (since there is an assignment inside `inner_function()` even after the statement the interpreter complains about `tmp = c`). So, normally the interpreter complains about a variable it has not been assigned a value but it's being accessed anyway.

So to make it clear, **python does not distinguish** between type of variable (as for example java does).

> What is a proper way to pass variables from "function" to
>   "inner_function"?

Use parameters is the proper way.

> Is there any other way than by parameter?

As mentioned by others you can use global variables but it's not recommended as approach.

> Why there is an error on "c" variable reference and not on "a" table?

As I mentioned before there is no distinction between different types of variables. What make them different is that you are assigning in variable `c` a value but just accessing the value of `a` for example in the other case.

This [specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13277359/3584765) (also mentioned by @raul.vila) provides a good explanation.

Finally, since it's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. There is a difference if you are trying to print a global (even implicit) variable in an inner function or you are trying to change the value of a global variable for inside an inner function.