# python scoping - child scope should have access to parent scope?

Tags: python, scope

From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules), child scope should have access to variables defined in the parent scope. However, in my case, I get an unresolved error on `count`. Any reason why this happened?

```py
def find_kth_largest_bst(root, k):
        count = 0
    def _find_kth_largest_bst(root, k):
        if not root:
            return None

        _find_kth_largest_bst(root.right, k)
        count += 1 #unresolved error here??
        pass
```

Comment: please include the full error message

Comment: Error shown with squiggly red lines underneath count, as `unresolved reference `count``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nonlocal` keyword to access variables from parent scope.

```py
def find_kth_largest_bst(root, k):
    count = 0
    def _find_kth_largest_bst(root, k):
        nonlocal count  # This will access count from parent scope
        if not root:
            return None

        _find_kth_largest_bst(root.right, k)
        count += 1
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is using Inner Functions, which is different from class inheritance. Another quastion very similar is this one:

[Python nested functions variable scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218895/python-nested-functions-variable-scoping)

from this question one answer says:

> " The documentation about Scopes and Namespaces says this:
>
> A special quirk of Python is that – if no global statement is in effect – assignments to names always go into the innermost scope. Assignments do not copy data — they just bind names to objects.

it means that you may solve your error with `global`  or `nonlocal`  statement

```
def find_kth_largest_bst(root, k):
    global count
    count = 0
    def _find_kth_largest_bst(root, k):
        if not root:
            return None

        _find_kth_largest_bst(root.right, k)
        count += 1 #unresolved error here??
        pass
```

Another thing here is that `count = 0` have double tab, or 8 spaces, while it should have only one.