# What is the difference changing label in Tkinter and changing a variable both with the same inner function at the same time?

Tags: python, tkinter

(Main.py)

```
from tkinter import * 
from second import numbers 

a1=0 
LABEL = tk.Label(text=f"Your value is:{a}", font=("Arial", 24, "bold"))
LABEL.grid(column=19, row=6)
```

(second.py)

```
class numbers  

    def function(self):
        root=Toplevel()
        my_canvas=tk.Canvas(500,500).pack()
             def function1():
                 e= min. + max. 
                 a=e
        return a #if I do this I cannot see my canvas,if I use return inside function1 nothing happens
```

#I can use a to change label as such;

```
                 global LABEL
                 LABEL = tk.Label(text=f"Your value is:{a}", font=("Arial", 24, "bold"))
                 LABEL.grid(column=19, row=6)
```

Even though I can change the "LABEL" using `global`,I cannot change "a1" variable with "a" at the same time in tkinter.

*When I try this solution:*

[Python nested functions variable scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218895/python-nested-functions-variable-scoping)

*solution is using `return` function, if I do this I cannot display my canvas*

My purpose is using "a" 's value and changing "a1"

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be a little more clear in your question? Right now, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Providing any error messages would also help, along with any complete attempts you have made to resolve the issue. For example, you mention "your canvas", but nowhere in your code is there mention of a canvas.

Comment: `c+d=e` is not a valid statement.  `numbers` is a class defined in `second.py` and so `import numbers` is also invalid (should be `from second import numbers` instead).

Comment: Hello @acw1668 thanks

Comment: Hello Sylvester, thanks I added additional information. I hope it s much more clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate the window and add a method that makes the changes you want.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def increment(self, inc=1):
        self.num += inc
        self.label.config(text=f'{self.num}')

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.num = 0

        self.label = tk.Label(text=f'{self.num}')
        self.button = tk.Button(
            text='Increment', command=self.increment
        )
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.increment(inc=10)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello Alex thank you for your answer but my calculation ends inside of an inner function. I can reach variables if my functions are like this but as you see my above question I want to use "a" inside of "a1".

Comment: Make the `app = App()` in a global state, like in flask, then you can call `app.increment(inc=10)` from anywhere. You can also uso `from file import app` to have access to it in a different file.

Comment: even I will not be able to ask questions again due to my ban :)  finally, I solved my problem by creating json file then I saved "a" inside the file then I read the json :)

Comment: Hello Alex, my code is really so much complex so  I don t  have such a skill that is importing your code inside mine :)

Comment: But you get the idea. It is never a bad a idea to refactor if you have a espagueti.