# Traceback (most recent call last): UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x

why am I getting mentioned error? Is there any better way to do this?

```
def a():
  t = 0
  def b():
    t+=1
    return  
  b()
  print(t)
a()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `nonlocal` statement which will bind access to the `t` variable from `a` function.
Though, I wouldn't use that approach unless required.

```
def a():
    t = 0    
    def b():
        nonlocal t
        t += 1
        return  
    b()
    print(t)
a()
```

More information can be found here:
[Python nested functions variable scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218895/python-nested-functions-variable-scoping)